# Showing several figures at once

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Consider a list of matplotlib figures called `a`. I try to draw them at once writing in the cell of jupyter notebook something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

for fig in a:
  fig.show()
```

However I can't get any figures drawn in the cell output.
Writing `plt.show()` inside the loop or after is useless.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: `plt.show()` should only be called once and should show all plotted figures. Could you post the definition of the figures as well as how they are stored in a list?

Comment: Typically you build up your `plt` object and then just call `.show()` once.

Comment: @AlexEshoo `a = b.values()` where `b` is a dictionary having features names as keys and features distributions plots as values. figures were create in `f = plt.figure()` manner

Comment: @Tony every `fig` is already a matplotlib figure object. By the way, just calling `fig.show()` also does nothing though calling just `fig` in the cell draws a plot

Comment: If you've called `plt.plot()` several times, the plots are drawn on the current figure and all figures can be shown by calling `plt.show()` not `fig.show()`. I'm not sure what you mean by "distribution plots as values".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option might be to use `display` to display the figures:

```
from IPython.core.display import display
for fig in a:
    display(fig)
```

[image]