# Matplotlib Object Oriented Code to display inline in the notebook

Tags: python, oop, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

Any ideas on how I can get this code

```
# -*- noplot -*-
"""
=============================
The object-oriented interface
=============================

A pure OO (look Ma, no pylab!) example using the agg backend
"""
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

fig = Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1, 2, 3])
ax.set_title('hi mom')
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel('time')
ax.set_ylabel('volts')
```

from the matplotlib example gallery at [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/agg_oo.html) link to show me the chart in-line in my notebook?

Please Note:

- I want to avoid using pyplot as I am trying to use matplotlib using their "Object Oriented" Library only
- I have no issues getting pyplot based plots to render inline in my notebook using the `%matplotlib inline` or `%matplotlib notebook` magic

This confusing Object Oriented API of matplotlib isn't necessarily rendering inline.

Should I be using a different canvas?

Using fig.show() gives me the following error

`AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasAgg' object has no attribute 'manager'
Figure.show works only for figures managed by pyplot, normally created by pyplot.figure().`

Also, this particular canvas doesn't have a show method. So I am totally lost on how to get these darn Obj Oriented plots to render inline.

Comment: Funny enough there was a similar question asked just yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45614123/showing-several-figures-at-once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display a figure which does not live in pyplot and has no figure manager associated with it, you can use `IPython.core.display`:

```
from IPython.core.display import display
display(fig)
```

[image]

---

Just note that there is actually **no reason at all** not to use pyplot to create the figure. Using pyplot, the code is much cleaner and will automatically show.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3])
ax.set_title('hi mom')
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel('time')
ax.set_ylabel('volts');
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch!!! I have found using pyplot a lot more intuitive and cleaner too. Would you know why the matplotlib literature recommends using the Object Oriented Interface (which I read as DO NOT Use pyplot) ?

Comment: In my knowledge, this is referring to the matlab style plotting, in which you can call plotting function in the plt module to draw many kind of plot without referring to any figure or axes object. I believe the second example, where you only use plt to create the figure and axes object and then generate the plot using their respective method, to be the generally accepted OO approach for plotting in matplotlib.

Comment: A reason  to do this would be if you need to specialize matplotlib classes :

`    class Figure_special(matplotlib.figure.Figure):
        def def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(Fig_pressure_overview, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self)
            self.add_subplot(111)
        def plot(self, data):
            # do some special treatment here to get x and y from data, 
            # tweak kwargs, etc
            self.axes[0].plot(x, y, **kwargs)`